# I want to save each row as a list

Tags: python

I want to save each row as a list.

when we have a example data :

---

```
location,temperature,gender
a,4,b
b,5,g
c,-4,b
```

---

my code :

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    
    line = line.strip()
    
    words = line.split(",")
```

---

In the code above, `words` are a list of each column. example :

```
words[1] = (temperature
               4
               5
              -4)
```

But i would like to get it in the following format.

```
data[1] = ( a , 4 , b )
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly well for me, look [here on output online](https://tio.run/##RY3BisJADIbveYqsXlqZWpZdQQSfRDxM27EbqJmQSRWfvk7n4OaQkO/LT@Rlf5F/lmX71c5J2464DfxAKRy2za7BPg7E4wlnuzVHzASA7hLVML0SwODN4xkvV4BbVJyIAxKvbp8sJ0@AuUor7lxGdkpS1f/yGXVIHysTWbVxmxqKXJ/svUjgoSqHmYsSW7Way/e1XpYp9t4osrNwl6DeZg1uzImg4N2v66BzBzdC75q8vAE) (also input). I just saved your words into another list `data`. I created [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64289998/941531) out of it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this using `split("\n")` but you need to assign your data to a variable as string using triple quotes.

```py
word = '''location,temperature,gender
a,4,b
b,5,g
c,-4,b'''

list = []

for i in name.split("\n"):
    list.append(i)

print(list[1])
```

result after print

```py
a,4,b
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly well for me, I just added saving your words into another list `data`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3BisJADIbveYqsXlqZWpZdQQSfRDxM27EbqJmQSRWfvk7n4OaQkO/LT@Rlf5F/lmX71c5J2464DfxAKRy2za7BPg7E4wlnuzVHzASA7hLVML0SwODN4xkvV4BbVJyIAxKvbp8sJ0@AuUor7lxGdkpS1f/yGXVIHysTWbVxmxqKXJ/svUjgoSqHmYsSW7Way/e1XpYp9t4osrNwl6DeZg1uzImg4N2v66BzBzdC75q8vAE) (Look into `Input` and `Output` windows at this link)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

data = []

for line in sys.stdin:
    
    line = line.strip()
    
    words = line.split(",")

    data.append(words)

print(data[1])
```

Input:

```
location,temperature,gender
a,4,b
b,5,g
c,-4,b
```

Output:

```
['a', '4', 'b']
```